# How to save data if a column is named "Model" in asp.net MVC 3 + EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I didn't realize the that naming a field "Model" might create an issue while saving it. It says "The value 'User Entered Data' is invalid.

Is there any solution to fix this? I don't want to change the name of the column as i'll have to fix the code and references at many places.

DataModel is defined something like this :

```
public class Price
    {
        [Key]
        public int RowId { get; set; }
        public Decimal LatestPrice { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string URL { get; set; } 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a [Column attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.aspx) to keep the same table schema and then change your property name. After you finish typing the new name, click the icon that appears at the end of the word and select apply rename refactoring to update any references.

Answer (score 1):

It worked perfectly fine as suggested by jrummell

```
public class Price
    {
        [Key]
        public int RowId { get; set; }
        public Decimal LatestPrice { get; set; }
        [Column (Name="Model")]
        public string ModelName { get; set; }
        public string URL { get; set; } 
    }
```